# What is the length of facebookId when using Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm migrating my iOS app from FQL to Graph API. My backend has a 32 bit numeric for facebook id. It worked perfectly, but now, when using Graph API I realized the facebook id is larger (because it's changed by a temporal facebookid), and I see an overflow in my data base, (exactly 2^32/2-1 but it doesn't matter).
Reading facebook docs I don't see how long can be the new facebook id.
Do you know it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook employees in the official developers group on Facebook suggest using **VARCHAR(255)** to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook docs, you should treat the `id` field as a `string`:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields

Comment: Thanks for reply. I knew it must be a string. I was asking about the maximum length of that string. Thanks.

Comment: You wrote that you use a numeric field as storage. Facebook does not specify the length of the id field explicitly.